# How to determine which SQLException has been returned / where's the error codes list?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sqlexception

I'm using **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** (If it means anything).
I want to be able to catch and properly process the exceptions I receive from MySQL. I want to know if the transaction failed, if there's already a primary key with the value I'm trying to insert, and all the other errors.

I want to do something like

```
try
{
    ... // Code
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    switch(e.getErrorCode())
    {
        case...
        case...
        default...
    }
}
```

I've tried looking, but haven't found any, only some entries which talk about C# / .net

The main reason I want this is to see if one of my transactions rolled back because of the Isolation level I put, in that case, I'll have to retry it. And of course, some other issues.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

drivers information is required, as the error codes returned are vendor specific. Please have a look at the following error codes for mysql, might be helpful http://www.briandunning.com/error-codes/?source=MySQL

Comment: Thanks for the information.
As mentioned, I'm using **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** on MySQL (Version 5.1 I think), and the connection is **JDBC connector 3.1.14**

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL error codes are all documented in the manual (surprise!)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-handling.html